# How to capture selectionStart and selectionEnd in Safari for ios?

Tags: ios, vue.js, textarea, mobile-safari

We have a component that allows users to save highlights of some of the text on our site. It works fine in all our other browsers, but in Safari in ios, it does not capture any of the selection.

We are using Vue, and this is the code for the form field. You can see we react to the @select.native event.

```
<b-form-textarea
    v-show="!highlight || editing"
    v-model="highlightableText"
    @select.native="selectText"
    :readonly="true"
    :no-resize="true"
    rows="10"
    ref="highlightable_textarea"
    class="ubcgs-highlightable-text"
>
</b-form-textarea>
```

The selectText method is like so:

```
selectText(e) {
    this.selecting = true;
    this.selectionStart = e.target.selectionStart;
    this.selectionEnd = e.target.selectionEnd;
},
```

On my iPhone, I can select some of the text in the usual way, copy it, and paste it in another window. However, so far as I can tell, the selectText method is never called. For example, this.selecting shows a separate text area when true, and it does not show.

Various answers and blogs that I've found seem to indicate that this approach should work, but they are from several years ago, and Apple likes to change things up more regularly than that. Is there some other event I should be listening for, or some other way to get the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding the event "touchend" worked. The working version:

```
<b-form-textarea
    v-show="!highlight || editing"
    v-model="highlightableText"
    @select.native="selectText"
    @touchend.native="selectText"
    :readonly="true"
    :no-resize="true"
    rows="10"
    ref="highlightable_textarea"
    class="ubcgs-highlightable-text"
>
</b-form-textarea>
```